# android ADB is not found

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to running an android application on my device, but, I have a lot of problems since I began the installation ...

I've installed the Android SDK Tools on Windows 7, which is located in C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk

I've created the ANDROID_HOME variable which is the same directory, and add into the PATH "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools; C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools;"

But when restarted the command line, when checking for "adb", it says that the command is unknown.
So I can launch adb with the exe files, but when doing a "adb devices", no devices are detected.
And, there is two tablet actually plugged (samsung nexus 10 and samsung galaxy tab SM-T310)

I checked for this too : https://plus.google.com/103583939320326217147/posts/BQ5iYJEaaEH but it doesn't work too.

But, on chrome, if I navigate to chrome://inspect/#devices, I see my device.

Can anyone help me ?!

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Samsung devices need specifics Drivers.

Download Samsung driver: [Driver Samsung](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117#none)

and create enviroments vars ->

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk

Path= *allyourtpath*;%ANDROID_HOME%;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools

Comment: It seems to work ! But adb command is only working inside the plateform-tools folder, even after adding the folder into the path

Comment: and i have the same problem with ant, which is not find by cordova, but is in the PATH ...

Comment: have you enable USB debugging in your device??

Comment: yes, the device is now recognize, thanks ! But, It seems that I have the same problem with ant than adb, even if I had them in the PATH, they are not found

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you have adb.exe in ADT\sdk\platform-tools. If so, run the command in ADT\sdk\platform-tools path.

Comment: Yes it is present in platform-tools. 
I can run "adb devices" from the platform-tools folder, but no device are found

Comment: Is your device enabled with 'USB debugging'. Also check you have the USB driver software installed in your PC. To enable USB debugging, go to developer options in the mobile and enable USB debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
1)First of all,enable USB debugging on your devices

2) Select Run -> Edit Configurations

3) Choose USB device in Target drop down menu

Click on apply and then OK

So now you might be able to directly deploy you app on the device connected to the USB (check with one of your tablet first and then try with both of them)